# Job scheduler does not work on program exit

Tags: c#, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

My code is a kind of sloppy but I have this problem. I developed a time/day scheduler but the problem is when I close the window of the program and then I reopen it, it works only for the next two scheduled tasks and for the third it  does no longer work.

I mean if I choose to run code every one minute and the time is 9:11 and then I will close the window for some seconds and then I reopen it it will run at 9:12 and 9:13 but not in 9:14.

[image]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        Test t1 = (Test)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();

        hourArray[0] = Convert.ToInt32(t1.hr);
        minutesArray[0] = Convert.ToInt32(t1.min);
        radioBoxArray[0] = Convert.ToBoolean(t1.radioBox1);
        radioBoxArray[1] = Convert.ToBoolean(t1.radioBox2);
        radioBoxArray[2] = Convert.ToBoolean(t1.radioBox3);
        radioBoxArray[3] = Convert.ToBoolean(t1.radioBox4);
        radioBoxArray[4] = Convert.ToBoolean(t1.radioBox5);
        radioBoxArray[5] = Convert.ToBoolean(t1.radioBox6);
        timeToCall = t1.StoreNextDate;

        InitializeComponent();


       button01_Click();
        // create reader & open file



        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //
    }//end constru

    CancellationTokenSource m_ctSource;


    private void button01_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        hour = (int)numHours.Value;

        int minutes = (int)numMins.Value;

        //create next date which we need in order to run the code
        var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
        var date = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day, hour, minutes, 0);

        var curDateValue = getCurrentDate(date, getScheduler());
        runCodeOnce(curDateValue, getScheduler());

        var nextDateValue = getNextDate(date, getScheduler());
        runCodeAt(nextDateValue, getScheduler());
        timeToCall = getNextDate(date, getScheduler());

        Test t2 = new Test();

        t2.hr = numHours.Value.ToString();
        t2.min = numMins.Value.ToString();
        t2.radioBox1 = radioButton1.Checked.ToString();
        t2.radioBox2 = radioButton2.Checked.ToString();
        t2.radioBox3 = radioButton3.Checked.ToString();
        t2.radioBox4 = radioButton4.Checked.ToString();
        t2.radioBox5 = radioButton5.Checked.ToString();
        t2.radioBox6 = radioButton6.Checked.ToString();
        t2.StoreNextDate = timeToCall;


        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, t2);
        stream.Close();


    }




    private void button01_Click()
    {


        hour = (int)numHours.Value;

        int minutes = (int)numMins.Value;


           //create next date which we need in order to run the code
        var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
        var date = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day, hour, minutes, 0);


        var curDateValue = getCurrentDate(date, getScheduler());
        runCodeOnce(curDateValue, getScheduler());


        var nextDateValue = getNextDate(date, getScheduler());
        runCodeAt(nextDateValue, getScheduler());
        timeToCall = getNextDate(date, getScheduler());





        Test t2 = new Test();

        t2.hr = numHours.Value.ToString();
        t2.min = numMins.Value.ToString();
        t2.radioBox1 = radioButton1.Checked.ToString();
        t2.radioBox2 = radioButton2.Checked.ToString();
        t2.radioBox3 = radioButton3.Checked.ToString();
        t2.radioBox4 = radioButton4.Checked.ToString();
        t2.radioBox5 = radioButton5.Checked.ToString();
        t2.radioBox6 = radioButton6.Checked.ToString();
        t2.StoreNextDate = timeToCall;




        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, t2);
        stream.Close();



    }

 //   CancellationTokenSource m_ctSource;





    private void runCodeAt(DateTime date, Scheduler scheduler)
    {

        m_ctSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan ts;


        if (date > dateNow)
            ts = date - dateNow;

        else
        {
            date = getNextDate(date, scheduler);
            ts = date - dateNow;
        }

        //enable the progressbar
        prepareControlForStart();

            try
            {
                TaskEx.Delay(ts).ContinueWith((x) =>
                {
                    //run the code at the time
                    methodToCall(date);
                    runCodeAt(getNextDate(date, scheduler), scheduler);
                }
                  , m_ctSource.Token);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
            }
    }

    private void methodToCall(DateTime time)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c C:\Doit.bat");

        //setup next call
        var nextTimeToCall = getNextDate(time, getScheduler());
        timeToCall = nextTimeToCall;
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {

                   Test t31 = new Test();

        t31.StoreNextDate = timeToCall;

        t31.hr = numHours.Value.ToString();
        t31.min = numMins.Value.ToString();
        t31.radioBox1 = radioButton1.Checked.ToString();
        t31.radioBox2 = radioButton2.Checked.ToString();
        t31.radioBox3 = radioButton3.Checked.ToString();
        t31.radioBox4 = radioButton4.Checked.ToString();
        t31.radioBox5 = radioButton5.Checked.ToString();
        t31.radioBox6 = radioButton6.Checked.ToString();
        t31.StoreNextDate = timeToCall;

        IFormatter formatter31 = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream31 = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        formatter31.Serialize(stream31, t31);
        stream31.Close(); 

        //MessageBox.Show(strText);
        }));

        //  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c C:\Doit.bat");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a *huge* amount of code to post, expecting us to read through it. How about you take a bit of time to come up with a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem? (Hint: the UI required is absolutely minimal...)

Comment: i just dont know where the problem is thats why i posted it

Comment: So you take the time to try to cut the problem down to size - take a copy so you don't lose your real code, then start removing everything irrelevant, such as most of the UI. All you need is something to show when the timer fires... you don't need any of the user inputs. You don't need any file access (unless I've misunderstood things). You need *just* enough for us to see the problem.